# Find an instance of time within a time period

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to find out during what shift periods someone completed from their log in and log out time. However, I would like excel to count it even when the log in or out time is 15 minutes before or after the time (as the log in times may not be on the half hour).

Currently I have:

```
=IF(AND("log in"< "shift end", "log out"> "shift start"),1,0)
```

This will capture if log in = shift start, but does not capture properly if they log in late or early to their shift, as there are multiple shifts - e.g. 11:30 - 12:30, 12:30 -2:30 etc.

Ultimately, I'm trying to find the number of shifts they completed? How do I capture the inaccurate shift times?

[Here is the set up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1LwN.jpg)

Comment: Dates in Excel are in the end just numerical values with 1 being one full day (24h). To add room for another 15 minutes you could just use `"shift end"+15/24/60` and `"shift start"-15/24/60` in your formula.

Comment: The problem is, I need a universal statement for when they log in. They could be early or late. Essentially it's a 15 minute window either side of the shift start and shift end.

Comment: What should be written in the table? 1/0?

Comment: More or less, just need to find the number of shifts (instances of being logged in during a certain time period).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the structure from your screenshot and the following formula (`tolerance` being a named range with the 15 minutes or `15/24/60`) in `D2:I2`:

```
=IF(AND($B2<=D$1+tolerance, $C2>=E$1-tolerance),1,0)
```

would give you the desired output as far as I understand your requirements.

```
 |A    |B    |C    |D    |E    |F    |G    |H    |I    |J    |K
1|Name |Start|End  |11:50|14:00|15:00|17:30|18:30|20:30|21:30|#shifts
2|hugo |14:15|14:45|0    |1    |0    |0    |0    |0    |     |1
```

Comment: Got it. However, They can sign in any time during those fifteen minutes either side (14:04, 4:07, 4:11, 4:12), which this doesn't quite capture.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the formula. It should have been `$C2>=E$1-tolerance`. And it does capture all cases within those +/- 15 minutes. Sign in for the 14:00 shift can be anywhere from 13:45 till 14:15 and sign out can be anywhere from 14:45 till 15:15.

Answer (score 0):

As been suggested in the comments, you can add/subtruct 15 min. from the start/end time of the shift. place this formula the the most upper left cell to calaulate, and drag it all over the table:

`=IF(AND($A4<=C$2+TIME(0,15,0),$B4>=C$3-TIME(0,15,0)),1,0)`

This is assuming that the row with starting shift hours is 2, and the row with ending shift hours is 3, if not, change it to the correct place, but remember to keep the referencing right:

[image: counting shifts]

I'm not sure how important is the setting in your screenshot, but it can be easily changed to fit it (though the last shift column is not needed).

Hope this helps ;)